# Visual Studio 2015 resetting web project to use IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have a web project in VS2015 that I want to run on Local IIS. I set this up in the project properties and it works correctly, but whenever I close and reopen Visual Studio it always resets the project to use IIS Express.

**EDIT:** this happens when I close and reopen the solution, even if Visual Studio has stayed open.

Why is this happening, and how can I change it? (Note - other users are working on the same project so I don't want to store my Local IIS settings in the project file as I assume this would overwrite their settings when they got the latest version of the code.)

Comment: Do you always open Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: I didn't previously, but I have started doing so in an attempt to sort this problem out. It hasn't made any difference though.

Comment: Try deleting the .vs folder; but be aware that you may be deleting other options/settings you have changed from their installed defaults.

Comment: This happens to my team pretty often. We haven't been able to determine the cause.

Comment: hmm... a lot of decent answers in this thread got down voted.  Without comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I edited the .csproj.user file and this fixed the problem. I changed `<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>` to `<UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>` and left everything else the same.

I still don't know why doing this through the UI didn't save, if anyone else can explain it I'll happily accept their answer.

Comment: I've had this issue too and it appears that if you don't change the URL then it doesn't save the setting. So I changed my Project Url, pressed save, then changed it back and pressed save again and it updated the file.

Comment: Thank you NibblyPig - that's better than the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: Changing the .csproj file didn't work for me, but @NibblyPig's fix did. Note: this is still an issue in visual studio 2017 (what I'm using), not only 2015 as the original question states.

Comment: Commenting to say both that @NibblyPig's fix worked for me, and this worked in VS 2017 (15.8.2).

Comment: @BenBarreth and its still an issue in VS2019!

Comment: And applies to all users as well as just yourself.
It would also appear even if you change the *.csproj setting AND get it to save, you must also delete the *.csproj.user file, otherwise when you re-open the solution the Start button will still show IIS Express (even though it will use IIS)!

Answer (score 5):

NibblyPig pointed out in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222049/visual-studio-2015-resetting-web-project-to-use-iis-express/32402547?noredirect=1#comment65629539_32402547) that:

> it appears that if you don't change the URL then it doesn't save the
>   setting. So I changed my Project Url, pressed save, then changed it
>   back and pressed save again and it updated the file.

I'm just putting this as an answer so it's easier to find, but full credit to NibbyPig for finding this.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the file `projectName.csproj.user`.  User specified preferences in this file overwrite the project settings.

Answer (score 1):

I select project and click "Open Folder in File Explorer".
Then find associated .csproj file and edit with Notepad++ works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't save settings how would you expect to persist it and be available when next time you open project? I understand your concern that your settings shouldn't affect other team members who are working on same project. Your concern can be taken care if you follow below steps. Whatever settings you will do will remain local and applicable to you only and other team members will not get impacted.

1. Go to project properties.
2. Go to Web tab on property page.
3. Untick "Apply server settings to all users as shown below.
   [image: Web project settings]
4. Click Save button in toolbar.

   This way your settings will be stored in xxxx.user file and not in project file.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I am saving the properties using the Save button in the toolbar, but I'm keeping that checkbox unticked. That's what I meant when I said "I don't want to store my Local IIS settings in the project file" because the checkbox says it stores the setting in the project file.

My .user file still contains the line  `<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>` but I don't particularly want to manually edit it as I don't really know what I'm doing in there. Hence trying to get the setting to save through the properties UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me using VS 2015 Update 3. This is related to what NibblyPig said.  But for me only worked when editing the project file directly.

1. Unload the project. (If the project is not loading at all just go to #2)
2. Edit project file.  The only entry that needs to be changed is (almost at the end of the file) `<IISUrl>`.  There is no need to mess with `<UseIISExpress>` configuration, you can leave it as it is.

An entry for IISExpress will look similar to this one:

`<IISUrl>http://localhost:123456</IISUrl>`

Change it to something like this one:

`<IISUrl>http://localhost/your_site_in_iis</IISUrl>`

Note: "your_site_in_iis" should be an existing website.

3. Save and close project file.
4. Close the solution (this one is important).
5. Open the solution again and the problem should go away.