# ASP.NET "Use IIS Express" in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I'm creating a new ASP.NET website in Visual Studio 2015 and I want to run the site using IIS Express. When I right-click the website project, the "Use IIS Express" menu option is not there. If I open the website using VS2012 the option does appear. Any idea on what I can do to make that show?

Comment: Are you creating the project from file-> new project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 resetting web project to use IIS Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222049/visual-studio-2015-resetting-web-project-to-use-iis-express)

Comment: That menu item (if was there in some VS releases) was never used by me, and I don't think it is a must. Check the link @CodeCaster provided and see which are the more common options to configure IIS Express in VS.